# temporary storage in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to store output of a query(which returns multiple rows) temporarily in Oracle. One of the ways to do this is using temporary table and I am using that currently. But the problem with them is that they stay around and cannot be created and dropped in a procedure willy nilly. Is there another object that I can use to temporarily store the output of a query to be able to use in the stored procedure ?

Here is my stored procedure for reference:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE procPrintOutput
IS
  l_stmt VARCHAR2(512) := '';
  create_table_stmt VARCHAR2(512) := 'create GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp(matViewLogQuery CLOB) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS';
  drop_mat_view_logs_stmt VARCHAR2(100) := 'DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON '; 
  drop_temp_table VARCHAR2(512) := 'DROP TABLE temp';

  ref_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(create_table_stmt);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('created temp table');
    DECLARE
    CURSOR LIST_OF_MVL IS SELECT * FROM USER_MVIEW_LOGS;
    CURSOR CREATE_MVL IS SELECT * FROM temp;
    BEGIN
            FOR TEST IN LIST_OF_MVL 
          LOOP
            BEGIN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('owner : ' || TEST.OWNER || ' - name : ' || TEST.MASTER);
              l_stmt := 'insert into temp SELECT SYS.DBMS_METADATA.get_dependent_ddl (''MATERIALIZED_VIEW_LOG'', '''||TEST.MASTER||''', '''||TEST.LOG_OWNER||''') from dual';
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_stmt);
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (drop_mat_view_logs_stmt || TEST.MASTER);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('view dropped ... ');
            END;
          END LOOP;

      FOR CREATE_SCRIPT IN CREATE_MVL
        LOOP
          BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SCRIPT : ' || CREATE_SCRIPT.matViewLogQuery);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(CREATE_SCRIPT.matViewLogQuery); 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('view recreated ... ');
          END;
        END LOOP;
  END;          
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(drop_temp_table);      
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Done! Table dropped');
  ROLLBACK;         
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: There is absolutely no need to constantly create and drop that temp table. Just create it once and be done with it.

Comment: "But the problem with them is that they stay around and cannot be created and dropped in a procedure willy nilly" And that's a problem, why?

Comment: Creating database objects (like temporary tables) dynamically runtime is acceptable in some database environments but not in Oracle. In Oracle that is an (unfortunately common) [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

instead of of temp table you can use collection in pl/sql and store all information that you need into the collection by `BULK COLLECT`

here small [example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html)

in my example I collect all DDLs for matviews and name of the views, then in simple cycle we can do any operations...

```
DECLARE 
   TYPE tDDL IS record (name varchar2(30), ddl CLOB);
   TYPE tblDDL IS TABLE OF tDDL INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   l_ddls tblDDL;
BEGIN

   SELECT object_name, dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', object_name) 
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_ddls
     from user_objects    
        where object_type= 'MATERIALIZED VIEW';

   FOR indx IN 1 .. l_ddls.COUNT 
   LOOP 
      --do what you need with collected DDLs
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('view dropped ... ');

      --your complex execute immediate logic here                    
      dbms_output.put(l_ddls(indx).name);
      dbms_output.put('     :     ');
      dbms_output.put_line(substr(l_ddls(indx).ddl, 100));

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('view recreated ... ');
   END LOOP;
END;
```